# Replace dll files for opencv and use in visual studio

Tags: opencv, dll, visual-studio-2015

I need to use dll files that I have been given and that are modifications of opencv dll files. I have tried to replace the dll files by their modified dll files in the folder opencv where my dll files are. But then in visual studio 2015 I get the error "LNK2001 unresolved external symbol".

How can I replace my dll files by the new ones and use them in visual studio ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: do you have the `.lib` files, too? were the `dll` files compiled with visual studio 2015? If not, you should use the same visual studio version that was used to compile openCV

Comment: No, sadly I don't have the .lib files. I was given modified versions of opencv_calib3d300.dll etc. I don't know with what version of visual studio they have been compiled. Can the unmodified version of the .lib files work with the modified .dll ?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm no expert concerning linking. Not sure whether it is possible to link to the dll's directly. I think there must be those declspec things used in the library or something... are you able to compile your project with the original openCV dlls?